# Detect if a Realm object comforms to a specific protocol

Tags: swift, realm

I made a protocol called `Synchronizable` and I have some of my `Realm` objects conformed to this protocol.

Such as :

```
class Comment : Object, Synchronizable {
// ...
}
```

I want to query all of local `Realm` objects, and retrieve all objects that are conformed to this protocol.

So I did something like :

```
func getObjectsToSynchronize() -> [Object]{
    Array(realm.objects(Object.self)).filter({
        if let $0 = $0 as? Synchronizable {
            return true
        }
        return false
    })
}
```

With `Object` the `Realm Object` type, but this type object by default doesn't implements my protocol, so I can't detect if the object is conform to the protocol `Synchronizable`, it says :

```
Expression pattern of type 'Object' cannot match values of type 'Synchronizable?'
```

Is there a way to do this ? I think I'm on the wrong way by querying in the `Realm object`.

**Wrong way?**

Maybe I have to create another `Realm` class object called `SynchronizableObject`that inherits from `Object` realm class.

This class will have a relationship to Realm objects that I want to be Synchronizable, such as :

```
class SynchronizableObject : Object {

// MARK: - Realm Relationships

dynamic var synchronizables : List<Object>()

}
```

And then I should query this class with the `Realm` object

Answer (score 0):

@AnthonyR you can't query/filter directly `RealmSwift.Object`, you must inherit your model from `RealmSwift.Object` as you'v done

```
class Comment : Object, Synchronizable {
    // ...
}
```

Then you can query/filter all objects of **inherited** type:

```
func getObjectsToSynchronize() -> Results<Comment> {
    return realm.objects(Comment.self)
}
```

If you explain a little more what do you want to do may be I can help you